# Finding the Marginal of $f_y(x,y)$ from the density function

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

So I have the following function $f(x,y)=10xy^2$ and I am asked to find the marginal of $y$ with the region being $0<x<y<1$.

This is my setup: $f_y=\int_y^1 10xy^2 dx$ This is correct right because we need to change the limits?

Comment: The difficulty I have is determining where my limits are going to be and visualization I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,Y)$ is a couple of random variables with joint probability function
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=10xy^2 \;\mbox{if}\;0<x<y<1\;\mbox{and} \; 0 \;\mbox{else}.$$
Then the marginal probability function of $Y$ is :
$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^y{10xy^2}dx=5y^4 \;\mbox{if}\;0<y<1\;\mbox{and} \; 0 \;\mbox{else}.$$